# Ajax jquery fetching

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering how I would go about incorporating Ajax into my PHP code to make the content load dynamically.

Currently it is something like this.
First a user selects a category:

```
<li><a href='?genre=sport'>Sport</a></li>
```

Which in turn triggers a part of a include.php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['genre']))
{
    $genre=$_GET['genre'];
}
$result=mysqli_prepare($connection,'SELECT * FROM songs WHERE genre=?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,'s',$genre);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result,$id,$title,$artist);
```

Eventually leading to rendering the result in some sort of a html scheme:

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
{
     echo $id; echo $title, echo $artist;
}
```

I understand that I would probably send GET JSON data over $.ajax and then retrieve it and run it through mysqli on the server.
What I would like to know is what would be the best recourse to get the data back to the html and how to place it in some sort of a repeating structure.
I cant seem to get my head around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not use to pure ajax, you may see [xajax](http://www.xajax-project.org/). You can use following code to simulate your case;

```
<?php
include './path/to/xajax.inc.php';

$xajax = new xajax();

$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION, 'getGenre');

$xajax->processRequest();

function getGenre($a, $b)
{
    $response = new xajaxResponse();
    // your db code here
    $response->assign('result', 'innerHTML', $result);
    return $response;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href='?genre=sport' onclick="getGenre('sport')">Sport</a></li>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Simply, js and php functions are synchronized.

However, I suggest you to use jQuery for your case

**Edit:**

If you want do do that with normal ajax, I can suggest you to use jquery template.

on php side;

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['genre']))
{
    $genre=$_GET['genre'];
}
$result=mysqli_prepare($connection,'SELECT * FROM songs WHERE genre=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,'s',$genre);
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result,$id,$title,$artist);

#arr = array();

while ( mysqli_stmt_fetch($result) ) {
    $arr[] = $id;
}

return json_encode($arr);
```

Ok, you have returned json, let's render it on js side;
Let say your html like below

```
<ul id="result"><ul>
```

And javascript

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON( "your.php" + $(this).attr("href"), function( data ) {
        var template = "<li><b>${id}</b> <b>${title}</b> <b>${artist}</b></li>";

        $.template( "yourTemplate", template );
        $.tmpl( "yourTemplate", data )
          .appendTo( "#result" );
    });
});
```

For more detail about jquery template, refer [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna look up xajax and try it out. The code looks very neat and organized!

Comment: When it worked, Upvote and confirmation would be appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am looking for a Ajax solution but if nobody else answers, I will confirm it out of courtesy.

Comment: @user3428402 ok then, you can see my updated answer. Simply, return json from your php and render it on js side with jquery template